# Use Chinese Bing Maps API

Tags: bing-maps

I am using the Bing Maps API on my website to embedd a map etc

I'd like to use their chinese API for my chinese visitors but I could only find the documentation for their "rest of the world" API. Any documentation in English on how to use their Chinese API?

Ideally, I'd only have to change this part: `<script charset="UTF-8" type="text/javascript"src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>`

What's the equivalent for the Chinese API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an old Chinese specific API for Bing Maps which I think you are referring to which has been deprecated for some time as the Bing Maps V7 control supports Chinese. Documentation on how to localize the Bing Maps V7 map control can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427600.aspx In this documentation you will notice that there are two documented options for Chinese:

Chinese – Hong Kong (zh - HK)

Chinese - Taiwan (zh - TW)

Comment: The idea was to hit a Bing server in China, not to have the map in Chinese. Right now, the map takes too much time to load when visiting from China.. What about the solutions you suggested in this answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8117b240-ec46-49a0-a2e1-8a35094e88d1/chinese-bing-map?forum=bingmaps

Comment: If you are in China then your requests will hit the Chinese servers. The forum post you mention is for an old, unsupported version of the Chinese maps which is now deprecated. Another option, when using v7, set the culture to zh-CN. This is culture code is still going through quality control so it is not officially supported yet. When this culture code is used it will download a modified version of v7 that is hosted in China. Note that since this is hosted on Chinese servers, accessing it outside of china may be slow.

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for. Hopefully the feature will be coming soon!

Comment: @rbrundritt any update on whether this feature is available? would love to be able to use bing maps api instead of Baidu for users in China

Comment: Actually, Bing Maps does have detailed maps available for Enterprise customers. You can see a demo of it here: http://rbrundritt.azurewebsites.net/demos/ChineseMaps/